# Can I use cooperative_groups::sync(grid) in child kernel (CUDA dynamic parallelism)?

Tags: dynamic, parallel-processing, cuda

I have a reduce kernel which using cooperative groups (Contains `cg::sync(grid)`, `cg::sync(cta)`, `grid.thread_rank()`, etc). When the reduce kernel launched from host, it works correctly. When the reduce kernel launched (as child kernel) from another kernel (parent kernel), I got an "unspecified launch failure" error. If I get rid of `cg::sync(grid)` from child kernel, there's no error.

Can I use `cooperative_groups::sync(grid)` in child kernel (CUDA dynamic parallelism) ?

Answer (score 3):

To this date the grid synchronization feature of the CUDA extension "Cooperative Groups" and the CUDA extension "Dynamic Parallelism" can not be mixed.

To quote the CUDA 11.6.0 [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g504b94170f83285c71031be6d5d15f73) on `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel`, which is needed for grid synchronization:

> The kernel cannot make use of CUDA dynamic parallelism.

EDIT: An earlier version of this answer stated that one can not mix the two CUDA extensions at all. When one uses cooperative groups without using the grid-sync feature, one does not have to use `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel` and therefore one should be able to use dynamic parallelism. I corrected the answer to reflect this.

Comment: does this mean only that one cannot launch kernels from a kernel called using `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel` ? or is it also the case that one cannot launch kernels using `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel` from a kernel?

Comment: @guillefix As you can see in the [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g504b94170f83285c71031be6d5d15f73), `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel` is a `__host__` function, so you certainly can't use it in device code. I.e. I think both are impossible for now.